# db object not iterable in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm searching for a record in Users db and then looping through all the records. The code is something like below.

```
email = "xyz@gmail.com"
data = Users.query.filter(email=email).first() 
for item in data:
    if item["age"] == 15:
        #do something
```

The above code throws error `Users object not iterable`. How can I loop through the records?

Comment: You use `first`, so there is ONE item, nothing to iterate on, what did you expect ?

Comment: What about `Users.query.filter(email=email).all()` ?

Comment: ohh yes, silly mistake. Thanks for the help @azro

Answer (score 2):

Because you only returned one row of data, it cannot be iterable. If your data is not null, you can use ‘data.age’ instead of ‘item["age"]’

```
email = "xyz@gmail.com"
data = Users.query.filter(email=email).first() 
if data.age == 15:
   #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

```
email = "xyz@gmail.com"
data = []
data = Users.query.filter(email=email).first()
if data:

    # ages = data['age'] # You can use this also 
    age = data.get('age') # Try This 
    # age = data.age #If you don't want to convert into a list
    if age == 15:
         print (age)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?